# How do I use variables as attribute names when using python mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to use variables in a python function to try and retrieve attributes with mysql connector

It seems to work only when I specify the name of the attribute in the query itself

```py
def insert(ids, added_attribute):
    insert = ''
    if len(ids) > 0:
        #insert scpecified attributes wanted
        insert += ' AND (%s = %s' %(added_attribute, ids[0])
        #for loop for more than one specified specific attribute
        for id_index in range(1, len(ids)):
            insert += ' OR %s = %s' %(added_attribute, ids[id_index])
        insert += ')'#close parenthesis on query insert
    return insert

def get(name, attributes = 0, ids = []):
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    #insert specific ids
    insert = insert(ids, "id")

    query = 'SELECT %s FROM (TABLE) WHERE (name = %s%s)'

    cursor.execute(query, (attributes, name, insert))

    data = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return data
```

I keep getting null as a return value

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
query = 'SELECT {} FROM (TABLE) WHERE (name = {}{})'
cursor.execute(query.format(attributes, name, insert))
```

{} is replacing %s here and to call the variables you just need to add .format() with the vars you want inserted in order.

Comment: It worked for adding the insert, but when concatenating the query; the attributes are added in as the tuple of strings[`('id', 'name')`] [I passed in: `attributes = ('id', 'name')`], it returns this error `mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)` @ZakM.

Comment: @lamWiI disregarding my solution, just looked back over your code, issue might be the lack of a % in the cursor.execute line wasn't able to test this. ex. `cursor.execute(query %(attributes, name, insert))`

Comment: I tried adding variables like that, It didn't work, seems like `cursor.execute()` takes a query and then a tuple of variables if you're using `%s`

Comment: could you give me an example of the queries your trying to run? ex `SELECT something FROM (Table?) WHERE ????` @IamWil